# Redirect back with input Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So i am totally done ;( I can't understand how to redirect back on Laravel with filled inputs

My simple code is:

```
public function postSignIn(Request $request)
{
    return redirect()->back()->withInput();
}
```

My view blade is:

```
<form action="{{ route('signin') }}" method="post">
            <div class="form-group {{$errors->has('in_email') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
                <label for="email">Your E-Mail</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="in_email" id="email">
                @if ($errors->has('in_email'))
                    <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('in_email')}}</span>
                @endif
            </div>

            <div class="form-group {{$errors->has('in_password') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
                <label for="password">Your Password</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="in_password" id="password">
                @if ($errors->has('in_password'))
                    <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('in_password')}}</span>
                @endif
            </div>
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

But every time all inputs are empty

What i am doing wrong?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`old`](https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-old) for all elements you need input, see example below:

```
<form action="{{ route('signin') }}" method="post">
        <div class="form-group {{$errors->has('in_email') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
                <label for="email">Your E-Mail</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="in_email" id="email" value="{{ old('in_email') }}">
                @if ($errors->has('in_email'))
                        <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('in_email')}}</span>
                @endif
        </div>

        <div class="form-group {{$errors->has('in_password') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
                <label for="password">Your Password</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="in_password" id="password" value="{{ old('in_password') }}">
                @if ($errors->has('in_password'))
                        <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('in_password')}}</span>
                @endif
        </div>
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thx ;) I saw this in video tutorial, but some people in comments told that it's easier to use 1 line "withInput()" than add value for each input. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have to put in the value using the `old('input_name')`

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="in_email" id="email"> value="{{ old('in_email') }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

you still have to populate your form fields:

example:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}">
```

Comment: Thx mate! I saw this in video tutorial, but some people in comments told that it's easier to use 1 line "withInput()" than add value for each input. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use blade in view file to avoid to use old('input_field_name') in every field. Writing your html code in Blade template, it automatically handle CSRF token and old input if any validation error occurs. Just rewrite your HTML code as :-

```
        {{ Form::open(['route' => 'signin', 'method'=>'POST']) }}
        <div class="form-group {{$errors->has('in_email') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
            <label for="email">Your E-Mail</label>
            {{ Form::text('in_email', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'email']) }}
            {{ $errors->first('in_email', '<span class="text-danger">:message</span>') }}

        </div>

        <div class="form-group {{$errors->has('in_password') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
            <label for="password">Your Password</label>
             {{ Form::password('in_password', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'password']) }}
             {{ $errors->first('in_password', '<span class="text-danger">:message</span>') }}

        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    {{ Form::close() }}
```